# Printing HTML without forced page breaks

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break-inside

I am trying to print HTML with lots of big blockquote elements spanning half a page each or more. When printing, the browser adds a page break in cases where the blockquote element will not finish within the current page.

I've tried this on several browsers and same thing. How would one program the CSS to display the blockquotes even if they will be cut in the middle at the end of the current page?

for example:

```
text-text text-text text-text text-text 
text-text text-text text-text text-text 
<blockquote>
text-text text-text text-text 
text-text text-text text-text 
</blockquote>
```

Browsers will add a page break before the "blockquote" element if its contents will not finish by the end of the current page.

How would one prevent this?

I've fiddled with CSS properties page-break-before/inside/after but that did not help.

Comment: I think you're talking about default browser styling, simply override them using css.

Comment: @reinierkors what property? that is my question. i've fiddled with page-break-before/inside/after but no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want one or both of these `page-break` rules:

```
blockquote {
  display: block;

  page-break-before: avoid;
  page-break-inside: auto;
}
```

...or possibly the preceding element needs `page-break-after: avoid`.

(You can also use the more recently-introduced properties [break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before), [break-after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after), and [break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside) -- but browser support for these is still, as of 2023, not complete.)

Per comments below, the element must have `display:  block` for this to work; `display: inline-block` doesn't trigger the page break behavior.

Comment: OK.  I'll admit I've never needed this property so I don't know if there are quirks to watch for; page breaks are generally controlled by `page-break-foo` properties so it's going to be one of those.

Comment: fiddling more. i found the answer. seems <blockquote style="display:inline-block"> was blocking this. i reverted to display:block and your solution worked. please edit your answer so i can upvote and accept.

Comment: @m.r. That's interesting! And rather surprising! I honestly have no idea why that is -- I'm glad I was able to give you a nudge in the right direction even if my answer was only half right...

Comment: display:block triggers the behavior. display:inline-block does not